# Ruby parse JSON without printing results

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I am parsing a file `input.json` to a hash like so

```
input_object = JSON.parse(File.read('input.json'))
```

When I run the script, either in irb or running `ruby script.rb`, the terminal I run it from starts to print the object. This would not normally be a problem, but `input.json` is a large file, and could take 10~20 minutes to print. Is there a way I can do this silently?

Update: Even with `irb_context.echo = false`, it prints. This implies that setting `input_object =` the object is not being printed.

Comment: nothing you have there should print to stdout unless you are in irb.

Comment: I added it to `script.rb`, and ran `ruby script.rb`, and it printed it in the terminal. I'm using ruby 2.1.2.

Comment: can you test it smaller, definitely valid json file e.g. test.json {
    "test": 123
}
?

Comment: Thanks @JariOtranen! I think that was it. Tested with http://json.org/example, the script runs silently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby shows the result, which is why IRB is printing the json.

There's a typical Ruby IRB idiom to append any short item, like this:

```
input_object = JSON.parse(File.read('input.json')); 0
```

The appended 0 makes IRB print 0 instead of the long json.

For your script, it is possibly printing the JSON because the JSON parser is hitting an error, and what you're seeing is an exception debugging message.

Try wrapping the parse:

```
begin
  input_object = JSON.parse(File.read('input.json'))
rescue
  raise "JSON parse error!"
end
```

Does it still print the JSON?

If so, try making the script executable:

1. Make the first line of the script this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env ruby
   ```
2. Make the last line this:

   ```
   exit 0
   ```
3. Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod u+x script.rb
   ```
4. Run it:

   ```
   ./script.rb
   ```

Does it still print the JSON?

Comment: Apparantly it is printing even outside of irb